# Get Browser Context Menu Items using Javascript

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

Is there a way to use javascript to programmatically get the context menu items that are available when a right click event is generated within a browser.

For example in Chrome be able to have an array filled with the following: Back,Forward,Reload,Save as, Print, Translate to English, View page source, View page info and so on.

Is it possible to get such values without the need for generating a right click event so the context menu doesn't appear on the user's browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get them. This would be a security issue, as extensions can add items to that menu and if you can get the menu entries with JavaScript, you can figure out if user is using a particular extension. The only thing you are allowed to do with the context menu is to stop it from showing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so as the context menu is at the application level and not exposed at the javascript level.